# Why do I get An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code on saving

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

**Exception :**

> Additional information: The operation failed: The relationship could
>   not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is
>   non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related
>   foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does
>   not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the
>   foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the
>   unrelated object must be deleted.

There are 2 foreign keys related to my events table, 1. venueId and 2. registrationstatusId

Following is my code.

```
var _context = new EventbriteContext(appKey, userKey);
expo.eventbrite.EventService service = new eventbrite.EventService(_context);
var ebEvents = service.FindByOrganizer(organizerId);
pacificCurrentDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);
AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
foreach (var item in ebEvents)
{
    var dbEvent = uow.EventRepository.Find(x => x.EventbriteId == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if (dbEvent == null)
    {
        dbEvent = Mapper.Map<Event>(item);
        uow.EventRepository.Insert(dbEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        var newEvent = Mapper.Map<model.Event>(item);
        string Startdate = (newEvent.StartDate).ToString("yyyy,MM,dd");
        string Enddate = (newEvent.EndDate).ToString("yyyy,MM,dd");
        string currentdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd");
        if (newEvent.RegistrationStatusId != 2)
        {
            if (dbEvent.RegistrationStatusId != newEvent.RegistrationStatusId)
            {
                dbEvent.Title = newEvent.Title;
                dbEvent.Description = newEvent.Description;
                dbEvent.RegistrationStatusId = newEvent.RegistrationStatusId;
                uow.Save();
            }
            continue;
        }
        dbEvent.Title = newEvent.Title;
        dbEvent.Description = newEvent.Description;
        dbEvent.StartDate = newEvent.StartDate;
        dbEvent.EndDate = newEvent.EndDate;
        dbEvent.EventbriteId = newEvent.EventbriteId;
        dbEvent.RegistrationStatusId = newEvent.RegistrationStatusId;
        dbEvent.Venue.Address = newEvent.Venue.Address;
        dbEvent.Venue.Address2 = newEvent.Venue.Address2;
        dbEvent.Venue.City = newEvent.Venue.City;
        dbEvent.Venue.Country = newEvent.Venue.Country;
        dbEvent.Venue.Name = newEvent.Venue.Name;
        dbEvent.Venue.PostalCode = newEvent.Venue.PostalCode;
        dbEvent.Venue.EventbriteID = newEvent.Venue.EventbriteID;
        newEvent.Tickets.ForEach(x => {
            var existingTicket = dbEvent.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(y => y.EventbriteId == x.EventbriteId);
            if (existingTicket != null)
            {
                x.Id = existingTicket.Id;
                existingTicket.Name = x.Name;
            }
        });
        dbEvent.Tickets.MergeUpdate(newEvent.Tickets, uow.EventRepository.context,
        (destination, source) => {
            destination.Description = source.Description;
            destination.EndDateTime = source.EndDateTime;
            destination.QuantityAvailable = source.QuantityAvailable;
            destination.QuantitySold = source.QuantitySold;
            destination.StartDateTime = source.StartDateTime;
            destination.LastSync = pacificCurrentDateTime;
        });
    }
    dbEvent.LastSync = pacificCurrentDateTime;
    uow.Save();
}
```

Below is the class

```
 namespace expo.model
 {

    [Table("Events")]
    public class Event : Entity, IEventbriteEntity
    {


        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        public long EventbriteId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastSync { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> LastAttendeeSync { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Timezone { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public string LogoSSL { get; set; }
        public int? VenueId { get; set; }
        public int RegistrationStatusId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VenueId")]
        public virtual Venue Venue { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RegistrationStatusId")]
        public virtual RegistrationStatus RegistrationStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You edit the dbevent.Venue object, which sets the FK to null (since no such entry is known in the database), without setting it to a proper value. Either set the whole Venue object to a tracked Venue, or set the FK after all changes are done to Venue.

Comment: In my case I see that after automapping the venueid is returning null  even though the venue id is very much there in the DB.I tried setting the value explicitly but still the same error.
Could you just throw us some light as to why Automapper is returning null venueid?

Comment: did you do the same for Tickets, Orders, ...? Well, EF knows dbevent.Venue is in the database, but you set the values to (possibly other) values, so Automapper has no idea if it should map to the same or another value, so it sets the FK to null to reflect your changes (of course it would expect a newly created object to not be in the database). When you want to set the venue object to newevent.Venue, you should set it altogether and attach this object to the context as well.